# Hibernate with nested set

Tags: hibernate

I have database with nested set structure. Which library can I use to work with this hierarchy? Google gave me the only github result (with just 8 stars). Looks like nobody else interested in it

In Doctrine2 I use Gedmo extension. I’m looking for similar plugin for Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation correctly, you have a database with hierarchical structure and you are looking for a library that is able to facilitate hierarchical queries (supported by SQL) on top of Hibernate.

The library that does that is [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Common-Table-Expressions).

Comment: Keyword is”nested set”

Comment: There is no notion of "nested set" in Hibernate (or JPA). Please describe what you want to achieve in generic terms without using PHP specific techs.

Comment: But Nested set is not php specific

Comment: Again, there is no notion (definition) of "nested set" in JPA. In my view it maps best to a table with hierarchical structure. But it seems that you mean something different. So explain the use case you have.

P.S. gedmo/doctrine are PHP, no?

Comment: I want hibernate to take control of “left”, “right”, “level” fields of entity. Also I want Repository methods like recover()/fixTree(), validate(), getRootParent() and so on

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM. It does not provide tree management API since from its perspective the data is saved in the database. Any data manipulation operations should be performed against the database (using SQL). Hibernate does provide an abstraction layer for some of those operations, mainly CRUD, see JPQL.

Comment: Looks like you’re not familiar with nested set and cannot help me. Anyway thx